# How to minimize virtual desktop window on Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualdesktop

When I connect to the virtual desktop using a windows 7 machine, I can still minimize it, or use Alt+Tab, or WindowsKey+Tab to switch between virtual desktop and other applications I have running.  With Ubuntu, I cannot do that, and have trouble getting back to my Ubuntu workspace.  How do I switch between virtual desktop and the other apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with VMWare View Open Client.  You cannot easily exit the Full Screen mode of the app.  Once you are in full-screen, you can try holding Alt key and clicking right-mouse-button.  That should pop-up a menu with a "minimize" option.  Problem is that this menu does not always pop-up, sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't.

Here is more info on it: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vmware-view-open-client/PvRDNjGSp4A